# How to find all places, which belong to a category like atms in an area, which is defined according to a radius or some latitutes and longtitutes?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap, here-api

I have to get all places, which belongs to a category like restaurants, atms, hospitals in an area according to a radius or some latitutes and longtitutes, which is defined by the user. As an example, imagine I want to get all the ATMs in an area. This area must be abled to define for the user. I want to get all these atms in that defined area. I couldn't find a query in APIs to fulfill my requirement. Can you please help me to do this?

I tried Google places api to do this. Following is one of a query I tried.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=6.927079,79.861244&radius=1500&type=atm&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I couldn't get all atms using this query. The output was limited in this case.

And I also tried Places (Search) API in Here Maps. But I couldn't find a way to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Read the documentation again. Results are limited to 20 (+20) (+20).

Comment: yes. Results are limited to 60(20 per once). But I have more than 60 results to get. Then, What I need to do? Can you please help me?

Comment: To get more than 60 results on the same page, you can use the parameter ' &size=1000' where 1000 is the max number of results on one result page. You can also do it in a more systematic way by paginating the results. Check the doc for this here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/paginating-results.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the manual is misleading.  It says that a query is required, but you can actually just do a browse/ query without a 'q' if a 'cat' is specified and you'll get all of the responses with that category near your 'at' (or restricted to your 'in'), sorted by distance.

So, to get 50 ATMs near the center of San Francisco, you can use a query like https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/browse?at=37.7672%2C-122.4425&cat=700-7010-0108&size=50&cs=pds...

For restaurants, it's a bit more complicated since there are many different kinds of restaurants and they all won't necessarily have the "Restaurant" category.  Some might only have "Fine Dining", for example.  But 'cat' can be a comma-separated list of categories, so the user can specify all of the subtypes to make sure they get all of them.

You need to set cs=pds and use the category ids from the places-category-system documentation reference below, so if users are typing in category names you'll have to do some transformation in your code.  If you are interested in looking for specific types of restaurants like Chinese or Italian, there's a set of food types that can also be put in the 'cat' parameter (ids need to be used there as well)

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-browse.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/place_categories/food-types-category-system.html

Comment: Your query for the center of San Francisco is works fine. But, if parameter 'size' is not in the query, the default size is 20. And I try to work with some custom sizes. Then, I got the maximum size is 100. I know this size says, that is the maximum number of results for a page. But I think, it is also the maximum number of results which can be get from the query at once. Am I correct? If I want more than 100 results to retrieve, what can I do?

Comment: @YashithChanuka the only solution I found for that is: You make an estimate: How big would be the square that would contain 100 places. Then you generate grid of GEO coordinates from this assumption. You feed the coordinates into the API with a script and collect the results. Beware, this may incur massive costs on the API.